# RS485 UART Rx Receive Event Handler not fired for all Tx Commands sent

Tags: uart, rs485, modbus

I am using **(1)**[Azure Sphere MT3620 Starter Kit](https://www.avnet.com/shop/us/products/avnet-engineering-services/aes-ms-mt3620-sk-g-3074457345636825680/) and **(2)**[RS485 CLICK 5V](https://www.mikroe.com/rs485-5v-click) and **(3)**[Geovan Board](https://www.geovan.com/board_kr/?ckattempt=2&mod=document&uid=469)

Here is the setup (I don't have latest picture, so #2 is swapped to first slot in the MT3620)

[image: hardware setup]

My **MT3620** is registered all good with Azure IoTHub and pushing all telemetry data to cloud. Now I am trying to sent some HEX commands from **MT3620** to **Geovan Board** via **RS485 CLICK 5V**

```
   static void SendUartMessage(int uartFd, const char* dataToSend, size_t totalBytesToSend)
   {
    size_t totalBytesSent = 0;
    //size_t totalBytesToSend = strlen(dataToSend);
    int sendIterations = 0;
    close(r1PinFd);
    r1PinFd = GPIO_OpenAsOutput(MIKROE_PWM, GPIO_OutputMode_PushPull, GPIO_Value_High);
    while (totalBytesSent < totalBytesToSend) {
        sendIterations++;

        // Send as much of the remaining data as possible
        size_t bytesLeftToSend = totalBytesToSend - totalBytesSent;
        const char* remainingMessageToSend = dataToSend + totalBytesSent;
        ssize_t bytesSent = write(uartFd, remainingMessageToSend, bytesLeftToSend);
        if (bytesSent == -1) {
            Log_Debug("ERROR: Could not write to UART: %s (%d).\n", strerror(errno), errno);
            exitCode = ExitCode_SendMessage_Write;
            return;
        }

        totalBytesSent += (size_t)bytesSent;
    }
    int c, d;

    sleep(5);
    close(r1PinFd);
    r1PinFd = GPIO_OpenAsOutput(MIKROE_PWM, GPIO_OutputMode_PushPull, GPIO_Value_Low);
    Log_Debug("Sent %zu bytes over UART in %d calls.\n", totalBytesSent, sendIterations);
}
```

Response Handler

static void UartEventHandler(EventLoop* el, int fd, EventLoop_IoEvents events, void* context)

```
{
    const size_t receiveBufferSize = 256;
    uint8_t receiveBuffer[receiveBufferSize + 1]; // allow extra byte for string termination
    ssize_t bytesRead;

    // Read incoming UART data. It is expected behavior that messages may be received in multiple
    // partial chunks.
    bytesRead = read(uartFd, receiveBuffer, receiveBufferSize);
    if (bytesRead == -1) {
        Log_Debug("ERROR: Could not read UART: %s (%d).\n", strerror(errno), errno);
        exitCode = ExitCode_UartEvent_Read;
        return;
    }

    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        receiveBuffer[bytesRead] = 0;
        Log_Debug("UART received %d bytes: '%s'.\n", bytesRead);
        /*time_t rawtime;
        time(&rawtime);
        if (returnDataUart == "") {
            strcat(returnDataUart, asctime(localtime(&rawtime)));
            strcat(returnDataUart, ":");
        }*/
        char  data_hex_str[sizeof(receiveBuffer) / sizeof(receiveBuffer[0])];
        get_hex(receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer) / sizeof(receiveBuffer[0]), data_hex_str, sizeof(receiveBuffer) / sizeof(receiveBuffer[0]), 16);
        strcat(returnDataUart, data_hex_str);
        Log_Debug("\s", returnDataUart);
    }

    char* pjsonBuffer = (char*)malloc(JSON_BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (pjsonBuffer == NULL) {
        Log_Debug("ERROR: not enough memory to send telemetry");
    }

    snprintf(pjsonBuffer, JSON_BUFFER_SIZE,
        "{\"gX\":%.2lf, \"gY\":%.2lf, \"gZ\":%.2lf, \"aX\": %.2f, \"aY\": "
        "%.2f, \"aZ\": %.2f, \"pressure\": %.2f, \"light_intensity\": %.2f, "
        "\"altitude\": %.2f, \"temp\": %.2f,  \"rssi\": %d, \"RS485\": %s}",
        acceleration_g.x, acceleration_g.y, acceleration_g.z, angular_rate_dps.x,
        angular_rate_dps.y, angular_rate_dps.z, pressure_kPa, light_sensor, altitude,
        lsm6dso_temperature, network_data.rssi, returnDataUart);

    Log_Debug("\n[Info] Sending telemetry: %s\n", pjsonBuffer);
    SendTelemetry(pjsonBuffer, true);
    free(pjsonBuffer);
}
```

When I put a breakpoint at `UartEventHandler`, it almost never hit it.
Can someone help me with the right delays or sequence of code?

Comment: A picture is not sufficient for someone reading this to help debug the situation, please (edit the) post a block diagram or schematic. Then reopen the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not waiting until all the transmit bytes have been sent before changing the rs485 bus direction. Under Linux using a usb->rs485 converter takes care of this in hardware. When using the on chip serial ports, you'll probably need to read up on the serial driver and use the RTS to control the bus direction. Failing that, add a delay of a few character times to allow the serial buffer to empty before changing the bus direction.

Comment: How do I determine the wait needed and I am doing the delay(1000) ms. that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I’d suggest you confirm that all bytes are being written out by using a usb->rs485 interface and terminal software on your PC. 1 second for a delay seems way too excessive - how is the addressed device’s response going to get through?

Comment: Have you wired he RS485 correctly? So easy to swap A&B wires. One person’s A is another persons B - there is a lot of confusion. Since I don’t know my Hangul from my Chaebol, i had trouble making sense of the geovan website.